# Deployment problem with java axis2 web services

Tags: java, namespaces, apache-axis

We are having a problem deploying our webservices, built in eclipse using java/axis2.

On local boxes and development servers some namespaces are generated as xmlns:ax21 & xmlns:ax23. But when deployed to test servers are xmlns:23 & xmlns:24.

All servers are using identical java installs.

This is causing problems with client apps trying to attach.

Can someone help?

1. Where are ax21 et al generated?
2. Can we control those? or replace them with our own prefixes?

Comment: What do you mean by deployment problems? Do the Web Services deploy or not? Do you get any exception on deploying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prefixes do not matter. They are just something like a local alias. What matters is the namespace URI. In both deployments the namespace URI should be the same. In most XML tools, not only Axis2, you can't influence the used prefixes. 
Unfortunately in some poor written clients the namespace matters. But these clients do not use a SOAP framework or XML library. What you have to replace is the client apps or you should introduce a SOAP framework like Axis2, CXF, JAX-WS RI, etc. at the client app.
By the way what technology do you use for the client?

Comment: Thanks, you are a star. This confirms what I've suspected. We have a web service that a third party client, written in java, is trying to access. As we've moved it from test servers to UAT servers, the prefix has changed and caused a problem with the third party client. We obviously need to have a solution before we go live and move to production servers. This sounds like it's the third party client problem.